# Why does Python 3 statistics module have the collections module as submodule?

Tags: python, statistics, python-3.4

Intorspecting the `statistics` module, Python list the `collections` module as one of it's submodules:

```
>>> import statistics
>>> 'collections' in dir(statistics)
True
```

Moreover, that `collections` submodule is in fact the standard Python `collections` module:

```
>>> import collections
>>> collections == statistics.collections
True
```

Why is this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have any submodules. `collections` was *imported*. Importing a module adds a reference to it to the global namespace. From the [`statistics` module source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/statistics.py#l102):

```
import collections
```

Modules are objects too, stored in the `sys.modules` structure, names in module globals are just references to those. So not only `collections == statistics.collections` is true, so is `collections is sys.modules['collections']`.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a *"submodule"*, `statistics` is just [*using* `collections`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/statistics.py#l296):

```
table = collections.Counter(iter(data)).most_common()
```

Comment: But statistics is exposing collections in his namespace (statistics.collections). Why?.

Comment: @jgomo3 because everything you import into your namespace is accessible from outside by default.